# How to set rect bar width to 1 minute in D3JS timescale bar graph

Tags: d3.js

I'm new with D3JS and I'm making a zoomable bar graph in a timescale following [this example](https://bl.ocks.org/misanuk/fc39ecc400eed9a3300d807783ef7607). I changed the circles to rects instead. Now I just can't figure out how can I make it so that the bar width is always 1 minute?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do this...

```
var parseMin = d3.timeParse("%M");
var oneMinWidth = x(parseMin("1"))-x(parseMin("0"));
messages.selectAll("message")
    .data(data)
    .enter().append("rect")
    .attr('class', 'message')
    .attr("width", oneMinWidth)
    .attr("height", oneMinWidth)
    .style("opacity", 0.4)
    .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.sent_time); })
    .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.messages_sent_in_day); })
```